# Find a list of slow rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

How can I find a list of the slowest rspec tests? I want to refactor those to run faster. I tried looking for gems but can't find any. I was thinking of putting something in

```
Rspec.before(:each)
```

and

```
Rspec.after(:each)
```

blocks to generate this list. But I don't know how to access the name of the spec.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

That's actually built right in to the rspec command. Just use the `-p` or `--profile` flag while you're running all your rspec tests.

Comment: As a note, the profile won't print if your specs are failing.

Answer (score 16):

As MrDan says, the --profile flag. You can also make a .rspec file in the root of your project, so that you get the timing information all the time, like this:

```
$ cat .rspec 
--colour
--profile
--format nested
--backtrace
```

You can also speed up all your tests generally by turning off garbage collection, like this:

```
# turn off garbage collection when running tests, place this in spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all) do
     DeferredGarbageCollection.start
  end

  config.after(:all) do
     DeferredGarbageCollection.reconsider
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get "uninitialized constant DeferredGarbageCollection"

Comment: https://makandracards.com/makandra/950-speed-up-rspec-by-deferring-garbage-collection

Comment: Deferring GC is a pretty interesting idea. @rob do you see any drawbacks at doing this?

Comment: Not really. I suppose you might run out of memory before you finish all the tests, but we have 99% coverage and 5000+ tests, and we don't run out.